# Table value duplicating. how to limit / make sure it only appear once pr row - powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, duplicates, office365

## The Issue

Hello!
I have an issue that i also describe again a bit more down here. but the issue is that this script adds the corresponding value of the "Count" column as many times in the same row, as the number is for a value in "Count"

##### example:

```
Count Name                                 SKUName
----- ----                                 -------
    4 f8a1db68-be16-40ed-86d5-cb42ce701560 Power Bi Pro, Power Bi Pro, Power Bi Pro, Power Bi Pro
```

Might sound confusing, because my english isnt the best. but i illustrate it further down.

this is the function *(the entire script is also a bit further down)*

```
cls

#List of company names in the tenant
$Companies = $Report | Select-Object Companyname -Unique

#horrible improvised "for" loop that goes through the list of companynames
$counter = 0 #starting at pos [0]

foreach ($company in $Companies) {
    #prints the current companyname
    $Companies.companyname[$counter]

    #formatting the table for the current companyname[i] where it shows count, name, and SKUName
    $Report | Where-Object Companyname -like $Companies.companyname[$counter] | Group-Object -Property SKU | Select-Object Count, Name, @{Name = 'SKUName' ; expression = { ($LicenseLookup[$_.Group.SKUName]) -join ', ' } } | Format-Table
    
    #then moves down 1 pos in the current companyname[i]
    $counter = $counter + 1
    Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
}
```

I assume that this line can be tweaked.

```
$Report | Where-Object Companyname -like $Companies.companyname[$counter] | Group-Object -Property SKU | Select-Object Count, Name, @{Name = 'SKUName' ; expression = { ($LicenseLookup[$_.Group.SKUName]) -join ', ' } } | Format-Table
```

as its the line that creates the output anyways.
any help here with this would be amazing.

below is as i said ilustration of the issue and the rusult i want to get. and also my full script. the script will promt u to login with a global admin account on a m365 tenant. and then  it will print a table with info over all SKUS/Licences for each company within that tenant.

---

## My script

```
cls

Connect-AzureAD

$Report = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()
$Skus = Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Select Sku*, ConsumedUnits 
ForEach ($Sku in $Skus) {
    Write-Host "Processing license holders for" $Sku.SkuPartNumber
    $SkuUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True | ? { $_.AssignedLicenses -Match $Sku.SkuId }
    ForEach ($User in $SkuUsers) {
        $ReportLine = [PSCustomObject] @{
            User        = $User.DisplayName 
            UPN         = $User.UserPrincipalName
            Companyname = $User.Companyname
            Country     = $User.Country
            SKU         = $Sku.SkuId
            SKUName     = $Sku.SkuPartNumber
        }
        $Report.Add($ReportLine)
    }
}

$LicenseLookup = @{
    'SPZA_IW'                                 = 'App Connect Iw'
    'AAD_BASIC'                               = 'Azure Active Directory Basic'
    'AAD_PREMIUM'                             = 'Azure Active Directory Premium P1'
    'AAD_PREMIUM_P2'                          = 'Azure Active Directory Premium P2'
    'RIGHTSMANAGEMENT'                        = 'Azure Information Protection Plan 1'
    'MCOCAP'                                  = 'Common Area Phone'
    'MCOPSTNC'                                = 'Communications Credits'
    'DYN365_ENTERPRISE_PLAN1'                 = 'Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement Plan Enterprise Edition'
    'DYN365_ENTERPRISE_CUSTOMER_SERVICE'      = 'Dynamics 365 For Customer Service Enterprise Edition'
    'DYN365_FINANCIALS_BUSINESS_SKU'          = 'Dynamics 365 For Financials Business Edition'
    'DYN365_ENTERPRISE_SALES_CUSTOMERSERVICE' = 'Dynamics 365 For Sales And Customer Service Enterprise Edition'
    'DYN365_ENTERPRISE_SALES'                 = 'Dynamics 365 For Sales Enterprise Edition'
    'DYN365_ENTERPRISE_TEAM_MEMBERS'          = 'Dynamics 365 For Team Members Enterprise Edition'
    'DYN365_TEAM_MEMBERS'                     = 'Dynamics 365 Team Members'
    'Dynamics_365_for_Operations'             = 'Dynamics 365 Unf Ops Plan Ent Edition'
    'EMS'                                     = 'Enterprise Mobility + Security E3'
    'EMSPREMIUM'                              = 'Enterprise Mobility + Security E5'
    'EXCHANGESTANDARD'                        = 'Exchange Online (Plan 1)'
    'EXCHANGEENTERPRISE'                      = 'Exchange Online (Plan 2)'
    'EXCHANGEARCHIVE_ADDON'                   = 'Exchange Online Archiving For Exchange Online'
    'EXCHANGEARCHIVE'                         = 'Exchange Online Archiving For Exchange Server'
    'EXCHANGEESSENTIALS'                      = 'Exchange Online Essentials'
    'EXCHANGE_S_ESSENTIALS'                   = 'Exchange Online Essentials'
    'EXCHANGEDESKLESS'                        = 'Exchange Online Kiosk'
    'EXCHANGETELCO'                           = 'Exchange Online Pop'
    'INTUNE_A'                                = 'Intune'
    'M365EDU_A1'                              = 'Microsoft 365 A1'
    'M365EDU_A3_FACULTY'                      = 'Microsoft 365 A3 For Faculty'
    'M365EDU_A3_STUDENT'                      = 'Microsoft 365 A3 For Students'
    'M365EDU_A5_FACULTY'                      = 'Microsoft 365 A5 For Faculty'
    'M365EDU_A5_STUDENT'                      = 'Microsoft 365 A5 For Students'
    'O365_BUSINESS'                           = 'Microsoft 365 Apps For Business'
    'SMB_BUSINESS'                            = 'Microsoft 365 Apps For Business'
    'OFFICESUBSCRIPTION'                      = 'Microsoft 365 Apps For Enterprise'
    'MCOMEETADV'                              = 'Microsoft 365 Audio Conferencing'
    'MCOMEETADV_GOC'                          = 'Microsoft 365 Audio Conferencing For Gcc'
    'O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS'                = 'Microsoft 365 Business Basic'
    'SMB_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS'                 = 'Microsoft 365 Business Basic'
    'SPB'                                     = 'Microsoft 365 Business Premium'
    'O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM'                   = 'Microsoft 365 Business Standard'
    'SMB_BUSINESS_PREMIUM'                    = 'Microsoft 365 Business Standard'
    'MCOPSTN_5'                               = 'Microsoft 365 Domestic Calling Plan (120 Minutes)'
    'SPE_E3'                                  = 'Microsoft 365 E3'
    'SPE_E3_USGOV_DOD'                        = 'Microsoft 365 E3_Usgov_Dod'
    'SPE_E3_USGOV_GCCHIGH'                    = 'Microsoft 365 E3_Usgov_Gcchigh'
    'SPE_E5'                                  = 'Microsoft 365 E5'
    'INFORMATION_PROTECTION_COMPLIANCE'       = 'Microsoft 365 E5 Compliance'
    'IDENTITY_THREAT_PROTECTION'              = 'Microsoft 365 E5 Security'
    'IDENTITY_THREAT_PROTECTION_FOR_EMS_E5'   = 'Microsoft 365 E5 Security For Ems E5'
    'M365_F1'                                 = 'Microsoft 365 F1'
    'SPE_F1'                                  = 'Microsoft 365 F3'
    'M365_G3_GOV'                             = 'Microsoft 365 Gcc G3'
    'MCOEV'                                   = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System'
    'PHONESYSTEM_VIRTUALUSER'                 = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System - Virtual User'
    'MCOEV_DOD'                               = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System For Dod'
    'MCOEV_FACULTY'                           = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System For Faculty'
    'MCOEV_GOV'                               = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System For Gcc'
    'MCOEV_GCCHIGH'                           = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System For Gcchigh'
    'MCOEVSMB_1'                              = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System For Small And Medium Business'
    'MCOEV_STUDENT'                           = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System For Students'
    'MCOEV_TELSTRA'                           = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System For Telstra'
    'MCOEV_USGOV_DOD'                         = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System_Usgov_Dod'
    'MCOEV_USGOV_GCCHIGH'                     = 'Microsoft 365 Phone System_Usgov_Gcchigh'
    'WIN_DEF_ATP'                             = 'Microsoft Defender Advanced Threat Protection'
    'CRMSTANDARD'                             = 'Microsoft Dynamics Crm Online'
    'CRMPLAN2'                                = 'Microsoft Dynamics Crm Online Basic'
    'FLOW_FREE'                               = 'Microsoft Flow Free'
    'INTUNE_A_D_GOV'                          = 'Microsoft Intune Device For Government'
    'POWERAPPS_VIRAL'                         = 'Microsoft Power Apps Plan 2 Trial'
    'TEAMS_FREE'                              = 'Microsoft Team (Free)'
    'TEAMS_EXPLORATORY'                       = 'Microsoft Teams Exploratory'
    'IT_ACADEMY_AD'                           = 'Ms Imagine Academy'
    'ENTERPRISEPREMIUM_FACULTY'               = 'Office 365 A5 For Faculty'
    'ENTERPRISEPREMIUM_STUDENT'               = 'Office 365 A5 For Students'
    'EQUIVIO_ANALYTICS'                       = 'Office 365 Advanced Compliance'
    'ATP_ENTERPRISE'                          = 'Microsoft Defender for Office 365 (Plan 1)'
    'STANDARDPACK'                            = 'Office 365 E1'
    'STANDARDWOFFPACK'                        = 'Office 365 E2'
    'ENTERPRISEPACK'                          = 'Office 365 E3'
    'DEVELOPERPACK'                           = 'Office 365 E3 Developer'
    'ENTERPRISEPACK_USGOV_DOD'                = 'Office 365 E3_Usgov_Dod'
    'ENTERPRISEPACK_USGOV_GCCHIGH'            = 'Office 365 E3_Usgov_Gcchigh'
    'ENTERPRISEWITHSCAL'                      = 'Office 365 E4'
    'ENTERPRISEPREMIUM'                       = 'Office 365 E5'
    'ENTERPRISEPREMIUM_NOPSTNCONF'            = 'Office 365 E5 Without Audio Conferencing'
    'DESKLESSPACK'                            = 'Office 365 F3'
    'ENTERPRISEPACK_GOV'                      = 'Office 365 Gcc G3'
    'MIDSIZEPACK'                             = 'Office 365 Midsize Business'
    'LITEPACK'                                = 'Office 365 Small Business'
    'LITEPACK_P2'                             = 'Office 365 Small Business Premium'
    'WACONEDRIVESTANDARD'                     = 'Onedrive For Business (Plan 1)'
    'WACONEDRIVEENTERPRISE'                   = 'Onedrive For Business (Plan 2)'
    'POWER_BI_STANDARD'                       = 'Power Bi (Free)'
    'POWER_BI_ADDON'                          = 'Power Bi For Office 365 Add-On'
    'POWER_BI_PRO'                            = 'Power Bi Pro'
    'PROJECTCLIENT'                           = 'Project For Office 365'
    'PROJECTESSENTIALS'                       = 'Project Online Essentials'
    'PROJECTPREMIUM'                          = 'Project Online Premium'
    'PROJECTONLINE_PLAN_1'                    = 'Project Online Premium Without Project Client'
    'PROJECTPROFESSIONAL'                     = 'Microsoft Project Plan 3'
    'PROJECTONLINE_PLAN_2'                    = 'Project Online With Project For Office 365'
    'SHAREPOINTSTANDARD'                      = 'Sharepoint Online (Plan 1)'
    'SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE'                    = 'Sharepoint Online (Plan 2)'
    'MCOIMP'                                  = 'Skype For Business Online (Plan 1)'
    'MCOSTANDARD'                             = 'Skype For Business Online (Plan 2)'
    'MCOPSTN2'                                = 'Skype For Business Pstn Domestic And International Calling'
    'MCOPSTN1'                                = 'Skype For Business Pstn Domestic Calling'
    'MCOPSTN5'                                = 'Skype For Business Pstn Domestic Calling (120 Minutes)'
    'MCOPSTNEAU2'                             = 'Telstra Calling For O365'
    'TOPIC_EXPERIENCES'                       = 'Topic Experiences'
    'VISIOONLINE_PLAN1'                       = 'Visio Online Plan 1'
    'VISIOCLIENT'                             = 'Visio Online Plan 2'
    'VISIOCLIENT_GOV'                         = 'Visio Plan 2 For Gov'
    'WIN10_PRO_ENT_SUB'                       = 'Windows 10 Enterprise E3'
    'WIN10_VDA_E3'                            = 'Windows 10 Enterprise E3'
    'WIN10_VDA_E5'                            = 'Windows 10 Enterprise E5'
    'WINDOWS_STORE'                           = 'Windows Store For Business'
    'RMSBASIC'                                = 'Azure Information Protection Basic'
    'UNIVERSAL_PRINT_M365'                    = 'Universal Print'
    'RIGHTSMANAGEMENT_ADHOC'                  = 'Rights Management Service Basic Content Protection'
    'SKU_Dynamics_365_for_HCM_Trial'          = 'Dynamics 365 for Talent'
    'PROJECT_P1'                              = 'Project Plan 1'
    'PROJECT_PLAN1_DEPT'                      = 'Project Plan  1 (Self Service)'
    'SHAREPOINTSTORAGE'                       = 'Microsoft Office 365 Extra File Storage'
    'NONPROFIT_PORTAL'                        = 'Non Profit Portal'
    'MDE_SMB'                                 = 'Microsoft Defender for Endpoint (Business Premium)'
}

cls

#List of company names in the tenant
$Companies = $Report | Select-Object Companyname -Unique

#horrible improvised "for" loop that goes through the list of companynames
$counter = 0 #starting at pos [0]

foreach ($company in $Companies) {
    #prints the current companyname
    $Companies.companyname[$counter]

    #formatting the table for the current companyname[i] where it shows count, name, and SKUName
    $Report | Where-Object Companyname -like $Companies.companyname[$counter] | Group-Object -Property SKU | Select-Object Count, Name, @{Name = 'SKUName' ; expression = { ($LicenseLookup[$_.Group.SKUName]) -join ', ' } } | Format-Table
    
    #then moves down 1 pos in the current companyname[i]
    $counter = $counter + 1
    Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
}
```

---

## THE OUTPUTS.

below is the ***Current*** output from my script. and as you can see. for every one licence the company has of a license. it writes the name of that licence as many times on the same row.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Company 1

Count Name                                 SKUName
----- ----                                 -------
    4 f8a1db68-be16-40ed-86d5-cb42ce701560 Power Bi Pro, Power Bi Pro, Power Bi Pro, Power Bi Pro
   15 f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d Microsoft Flow Free, Microsoft Flow Free, Microsoft Flow Free, Microsoft Flow Free, Microsoft Flow Free, Microsoft Flow Free, Microsoft Flow Free, Microsoft Flow Free, Microsoft Flow Free, M...
    2 cbdc14ab-d96c-4c30-b9f4-6ada7cdc1d46 Microsoft 365 Business Premium, Microsoft 365 Business Premium
   29 4b9405b0-7788-4568-add1-99614e613b69 Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange...
   44 f245ecc8-75af-4f8e-b61f-27d8114de5f3 Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business St... 
    6 a403ebcc-fae0-4ca2-8c8c-7a907fd6c235 Power Bi (Free), Power Bi (Free), Power Bi (Free), Power Bi (Free), Power Bi (Free), Power Bi (Free)
    3 710779e8-3d4a-4c88-adb9-386c958d1fdf Microsoft Teams Exploratory, Microsoft Teams Exploratory, Microsoft Teams Exploratory
   59 3b555118-da6a-4418-894f-7df1e2096870 Microsoft 365 Business Basic, Microsoft 365 Business Basic, Microsoft 365 Business Basic, Microsoft 365 Business Basic, Microsoft 365 Business Basic, Microsoft 365 Business Basic, Microsoft ...
   10 1e1a282c-9c54-43a2-9310-98ef728faace Dynamics 365 For Sales Enterprise Edition, Dynamics 365 For Sales Enterprise Edition, Dynamics 365 For Sales Enterprise Edition, Dynamics 365 For Sales Enterprise Edition, Dynamics 365 For S... 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Company 2

Count Name                                 SKUName
----- ----                                 -------
    3 f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d Microsoft Flow Free, Microsoft Flow Free, Microsoft Flow Free
   36 4b9405b0-7788-4568-add1-99614e613b69 Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange Online (Plan 1), Exchange... 
   12 f245ecc8-75af-4f8e-b61f-27d8114de5f3 Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business St... 
    2 710779e8-3d4a-4c88-adb9-386c958d1fdf Microsoft Teams Exploratory, Microsoft Teams Exploratory


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

##### What i wish the output to be like:

this is very messy. So i would like it to be like this below.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Company 1

Count Name                                 SKUName
----- ----                                 -------
    4 f8a1db68-be16-40ed-86d5-cb42ce701560 Power Bi Pro, Power Bi Pro
   15 f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d Microsoft Flow Free
    2 cbdc14ab-d96c-4c30-b9f4-6ada7cdc1d46 Microsoft 365 Business Premium
   29 4b9405b0-7788-4568-add1-99614e613b69 Exchange Online (Plan 1)
   44 f245ecc8-75af-4f8e-b61f-27d8114de5f3 Microsoft 365 Business Standard
    6 a403ebcc-fae0-4ca2-8c8c-7a907fd6c235 Power Bi (Free)
    3 710779e8-3d4a-4c88-adb9-386c958d1fdf Microsoft Teams Exploratory
   59 3b555118-da6a-4418-894f-7df1e2096870 Microsoft 365 Business Basic
   10 1e1a282c-9c54-43a2-9310-98ef728faace Dynamics 365 For Sales Enterprise Edition


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Company 2

Count Name                                 SKUName
----- ----                                 -------
    3 f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d Microsoft Flow Free
   36 4b9405b0-7788-4568-add1-99614e613b69 Exchange Online (Plan 1)
   12 f245ecc8-75af-4f8e-b61f-27d8114de5f3 Microsoft 365 Business Standard
    2 710779e8-3d4a-4c88-adb9-386c958d1fdf Microsoft Teams Exploratory


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `($LicenseLookup[$_.Group.SKUName |Sort-Object -Unique]) -join ', '`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks! But i had to move the bracket from behind `Unique`, back to behind `.SKUName`. but thanku again. you have helped me a lot of times now! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MathiasR.Jesse said in his comment. the fix was to change the `$Report` to use this:

`($LicenseLookup[$_.Group.SKUName] | Sort-Object -Unique) -join ', '`

---

#### Function updated below.

```
cls

#List of company names in the tenant
$Companies = $Report | Select-Object Companyname -Unique

#horrible improvised "for" loop that goes through the list of companynames
$counter = 0 #starting at pos [0]

foreach ($company in $Companies) {
    #prints the current companyname
    $Companies.companyname[$counter]

    #formatting the table for the current companyname[i] where it shows count, name, and SKUName
    $Report | Where-Object Companyname -like $Companies.companyname[$counter] | Group-Object -Property SKU | Select-Object Count, Name, @{Name = 'SKU Name' ; expression = { ($LicenseLookup[$_.Group.SKUName] | Sort-Object -Unique) -join ', ' } } | Format-Table
    
    #then moves down 1 pos in the current companyname[i]
    $counter = $counter + 1
    Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
}
```

#### The $Report table alone:

```
$Report | Where-Object Companyname -like $Companies.companyname[$counter] | Group-Object -Property SKU | Select-Object Count, Name, @{Name = 'SKU Name' ; expression = { ($LicenseLookup[$_.Group.SKUName] | Sort-Object -Unique) -join ', ' } } | Format-Table
```